# How to go to Question that I commented on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page with a list of comments I made on other people's questions. Clicking on a comment should go to a page with just that person's question, along with all the comments on that question. So far I haven't been able to figure it out. I have the following code:

On each comment:

```rb
<%= link_to question_path(c.question_id), style:"color:black;" do %>
comment stuff
<% end %>
```

This is possible because each comment has question_id. Each question does not have comment_id.

Clearly this (on the single question page) does not work. Not sure what would. I'd really appreciate help.

```rb
<% @questions.where(id: c.question_id).each do |question| %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the question and comment in `show` method of question controller.

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @question.comments # if has_many :comments setup
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
# app/models/question.rb
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end

# app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :questions

# in the view of your comments
<%= link_to question_path(c.question), style:"color:black;" do %>
comment stuff
<% end %>

# app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
def show
  @question = Question.includes(:comments).find(params[:id])
end

# app/views/questions/show.html.erb
<%= @question %>
<% @question.comments.each do |c| %>
  <!-- show each comment -->
<% end %>
```